# Mi querybuilder no funciona bien con addcslashes

Tags: php, symfony4, doctrine, querybuilder

Intento hacer una consulta que me recoja todos los datos de la tabla donde aparezca lo que escriba pero solo me funciona sin addcslashes osea tiene que ser lo mismo lo que escribo que lo hay en la bbdd.

```
public function findByValue($value)
{
    $value = '%'.addcslashes($value, '%_').'%';
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orWhere('u.name = :val')
        ->orWhere('u.surname = :val')
        ->orWhere('u.email = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: que deberia tener la variable al final `$value`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function findByValue($value)
{
    $value = '%'.addcslashes($value, '%_').'%';
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orWhere('u.name like :val1')
        ->orWhere('u.surname like :val2')
        ->orWhere('u.email like :val3')
        ->setParameter('val1', $value)
        ->setParameter('val2', $value)
        ->setParameter('val3', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```